# Haskell persistent w/ esqueleto: read entire table, and count records

Tags: database, haskell, esqueleto

I have the following schema:

```
share [ mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll" ] [persistLowerCase|
AdminChan
  timestamp T.Text
  name      T.Text
  msg       T.Text
BanHost
  timestamp T.Text
  host      T.Text
  isBanned  Bool
  reason    T.Text
|]
```

Now say I want to get all the records in the `admin_chan` table in the form of `[AdminChan]`. How can I do that? I have this function:

```
dumpDbTbl :: SqlPersistT IO [AdminChan]
dumpDbTbl = map entityVal <$> (select . from $ return)
```

1) But how do I get the `[AdminChan]` out of the `SqlPersistT IO` stack? (Note that I'm not using `yesod`.)

2) Also, is it possible to rewrite the above function such that it becomes polymorphic and can also work with the `BanHost` table?

3) How can I write a function, using `esqueleto`, that will return the number of records in a table?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You use a function like [`runSqlPersistM`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-2.2/docs/Database-Persist-Sql.html#v:runSqlPersistM) or [`runSqlPersistMPool`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-2.2/docs/Database-Persist-Sql.html#v:runSqlPersistMPool) to evaluate your query in the `IO` monad. For example:

   ```
   dumpDbTbl :: (MonadIO m) => SqlPersistT m [AdminChan]
   dumpDbTbl = map entityVal <$> (select . from $ return)

   main :: IO ()
   main = runStderrLoggingT $ withSqlitePool ":memory:" 4 $ \pool -> liftIO $ do
       flip runSqlPersistMPool pool $ do
           runMigration migrateAll

           admins <- dumpDbTbl

           liftIO $ print (admins :: [AdminChan])
   ```
2. Yes, you can, but you have to include some extra constraints:

   ```
   dumpDbTbl :: (PersistEntity b, MonadIO m,
                 PersistEntityBackend b ~ SqlBackend) => SqlPersistT m [b]
   dumpDbTbl = map entityVal <$> (select . from $ return)
   ```
3. You use the esqueleto function [`countRows`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/esqueleto-2.4.1/docs/Database-Esqueleto-Internal-Language.html#v:countRows):

   ```
   countHostBans :: (MonadIO m) => SqlPersistT m [(T.Text, Int)]
   countHostBans =
       map (\(Value v, Value c) -> (v, c)) <$> (select $ from $ \banHost -> do
           let c = countRows
           groupBy (banHost ^. BanHostHost)
           return (banHost ^. BanHostHost, c))
   ```